# C++: Get state of linear congruential generator

Tags: random

It seems that if I write

```
#include <random>
std::minstd_rand engine(1);

std::cout << engine;
```

then this prints out the internal *state* of the engine (which is a linear congruential generator). Right now the state equals the seed (1), but if I call a random number and print out `engine`, it returns some large number, which is probably the state.

How do I actually *get* the state, in a variable?

Comment: When tagging your question, include the main language that you're using so that those who are looking to solve `c++` questions will see it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a string stream instead of stdout. Example:

`#include <sstream>
...
std::ostringstream os;
os << engine;
string mystate = os.str();`

The `o` in `ostringstream` is for output.

The state should be last random number generated, which is why there is not an easier way to do this. It's not as ideal as something like `int a; a << engine`, but it'll have to do. If you need it that often, make the stringstream operation a function (Including perhaps a conversion from string to integer). You can also typedef a pair of engine/integer with the integer being the state, and make a couple of methods so it's autoset every generation call if you need the performance.

If you don't care about the state, and just want it for the future, do

`int engineState = engine();`

Now you have the state. Though it's not the same as what it was before, it might not matter depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Output from linear congruential RNG is the state. Or, as alreadynoted, use `operator<<` to output and convert state

Code

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    auto engine = std::minstd_rand{ 1 };

    auto q = engine();

    auto os = std::ostringstream{};

    os << engine;
    auto r = std::stoul(os.str()); // use ul to fit output

    std::cout << q << "   " << os.str() << "   " << r << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
48271   48271   48271
```

Alternative might be if particular implementation implements `discard` properly in O(log<sub>2</sub>(N)) time, according to paper by F.Brown https://laws.lanl.gov/vhosts/mcnp.lanl.gov/pdf_files/anl-rn-arb-stride.pdf. In such case you could move one position back, call RNG again and get your state as output.

Compiler and library I use - Visual C++ 2017 15.7 - has not implemented discard in such way, and useless for moving back.

Answer (score 0):

LCGs consist of a simple state that is represented by a single integer.
This means you can treat `this` pointer as a pointer to an integer.
Below, I have provided an example of a template function that gets
the state (seed) of an engine and even works for classes deriving LCGs.

```
#include <random>
template <class T, T... v>
T getSeed(std::linear_congruential_engine<T, v...>& rand) {
    static_assert(sizeof(rand) == sizeof(T));
    return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&rand);
}

#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::minstd_rand engine(19937);
    auto seed = getSeed(engine);
    std::cout << sizeof(engine); 
    std::cout << '\t' << seed;
}
```

^ This method is way more efficient (x320 times) than serializing through a stream,
or by creating a dummy `ostream` and specializing `std::operator<<` for every case.

```
template<class T, T... v>
using LCG = std::linear_congruential_engine<T, v...>;
#define DummyRandSpec32 uint_fast32_t, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xCAFE, 0xFFFFFFFF
typedef LCG<DummyRandSpec32> DummyRand32; // the same engine type

template<class T, class R>
T* getSeed(R& rand) // getSeed 70:1 nextInt
{   // creating stream is heavy operation
    // return rand._M_x; // cannot access private
    __dummy_ostream<T> dumdum; // workaround
    auto& didey = *reinterpret_cast<DummyRand32*>(&rand);
    std::operator<<(dumdum, didey); // specialized
    return dumdum.retrieve(); // pointer to state
}

int main() {
    std::minstd_rand engine(19937);
    std::cout << *getSeed<uint_fast32_t>(engine); 
    std::cout << std::endl << engine << std::endl;
}
```

^ Here is ill-coded my first attempt at a solution, if you want to compare.
It is worth mentioning that a field name of the state is implementation-specific.
Purposefully left out `std::operator<<` and `__dummy_ostream`.